# C# HttpListener will show ObjectDisposedException if you stop listen after start listen immediately

Tags: c#, .net, httplistener, objectdisposedexception

Today, I am writing a framework which is using `.NET Framework 4.8`. There is a `HttpListener` in my code, which used to get message from the target website, and the code works fine. However, when I started the listener and stopped it immediately, it showed me the `ObjectDisposedException` error. In that case, I tried to use single step debugging and the interesting thing is that nothing was wrong.

In that case, I tried to delete some code and here is the minimal reproducible code:

```
HttpListener httpListener = new HttpListener();
httpListener.Start();
httpListener.Stop();
```

When I run it, it will show me the `ObjectDisposedException` error at line 3(`httpListener.Stop();`), and if you stack trace the code, it shows that the error will happen in line 150 of the `SafeHandle.cs`:

```
throw new ObjectDisposedException(nameof(SafeHandle), SR.ObjectDisposed_SafeHandleClosed);
```

However, I can not understand that much code, what happened, and what caused that error without taking a lot of time, so **I am wondering why that will happen.**

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have a real explanation, but if you take a look at the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/HttpListener.cs), you can see that the [*Stop()* method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/HttpListener.cs,961) calls *CheckDisposed()*, which throws the given exception, when [*m_State==State.Closed*](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/HttpListener.cs,2512). The only ways to set the state explicit by a method call to this value are the methods [*Abort()*](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/HttpListener.cs,1042) and [*Dispose()*](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/HttpListener.cs,1084). Additionally exceptions in [*SetupV2Config()*](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/HttpListener.cs,825) and [*Start()*](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/HttpListener.cs,874) could enforce this state, but would also *throw* a few lines later.

So this is not *a real answer* to your question. But at least it shows the points, when this error could occur and maybe someone else is able to *dig deeper* or better explain why this error occurs with the given information.